# `selector` return the value on page refresh, `onInit` value shows as undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-selectors

I am triggering a dispatch on `onInit` of the `shell component`, but getting the value as `undefined`. in case if i refresh the page, the value return properly from `selector`. do not know how to fix this. not getting any error too.. `users` part of actions works fine.

here is the action:

```
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";
import { PropUsers, PropUser } from "./reducer";

export const userActions = {
    GET_USERS: '[users] Get Users',
    GET_USERS_SUCESS: '[users] Get Users Success',
    GET_USERS_FAILURE: '[users] Get Users Failure',

    GET_PROFILE: '[users] Get Users',
    GET_PROFILE_SUCESS: '[users] Get Users Success',
    GET_PROFLE_FAILURE: '[users] Get Users Failure',
}

export const actionGetUsers = createAction(userActions.GET_USERS);
export const actionGetUsersSuccess = createAction(userActions.GET_USERS_SUCESS, props<{ users: PropUsers[] }>());
export const actionGetUsersFailure = createAction(userActions.GET_USERS_FAILURE, props<{ error: string }>());

export const actionGetProfile = createAction(userActions.GET_PROFILE);
export const actionGetProfileSuccess = createAction(userActions.GET_PROFILE_SUCESS, props<{ user: PropUser }>());
export const actionGetProfileFailure = createAction(userActions.GET_PROFLE_FAILURE, props<{ error: string }>());
```

selector:

```
import { createSelector, createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
const usersSelector = createFeatureSelector<any>("store");

export const selectUsers = createSelector(usersSelector, (state) => {
    return state.reducerUser.users;
})
export const selectProfile = createSelector(usersSelector, (state) => {
    console.log('state', state.reducerUser.profile);
    return state.reducerUser.profile;
})
```

shell component:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Store, select } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { PropUser } from '../../store/reducer';
import { actionGetProfile } from './../../store/actions';
import { selectProfile } from "./../../store/selectors";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shell-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './shell-user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shell-user-profile.component.scss']
})
export class ShellUserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() userProfile$: Observable<PropUser> = new EventEmitter<PropUser>();
  @Output() standClass: string;

  constructor(private readonly store: Store) {
    this.standClass = '12th';
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(actionGetProfile());
    this.store.select(selectProfile).subscribe(data => console.log('data', data)); //undefined until refresh the page
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use different string values for your actions.

```
GET_USERS: '[users] Get Users',
```

is the same as

```
GET_PROFILE: '[users] Get Users',
```

So even though it seems like you are triggering a different action (because you use another symbol), you are actually triggering the same action that fetches the users.

Every one of your actions should have a different string value. Try this instead:

```
GET_PROFILE: '[users] Get Profile',
GET_PROFILE_SUCESS: '[users] Get Profile Success',
GET_PROFLE_FAILURE: '[users] Get Profile Failure',
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. Good catch

Comment: That's a very good point. I used to copy and paste the actions. That caused triggering two unrelated actions with different names but same string values.